# Wordpress css show images float

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

I try put under the post 2 images beside and to the right , just under and float right , the problem it´s always show these two images one up and the other down of this

My code it´s this :

```
<div style="clear:both;float:right;">
<a onclick="increase_text(1)" href="#"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/text_increase.png" style="float:left;"></a> 
<a onclick="decrease_text(1)" href="#"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/text_decrease.png" style="float:left;"></a>
</div>
<br/>
```

How i can show this show images in the same line and float right ? , thank´s

Comment: You can set some width with float to both of them. Then they will be in one line(row). If you will do float:right than first image will be in right and second will be in left of first image.

Comment: I think you have to set width to fit in that row and they will be floated. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXhL6/)

Comment: Yes the problem it´s with wordpress , if you put space into the code of function when create shortcode , the core of wordpress addd the tag <p> and by this i see one image up and other down , the solution put the code without spaces and works fine with float left , regards

Comment: Its wokring fine with side by side and float:right. see below 

<div style="clear:both;float:right;">
<a onclick="increase_text(1)" href="#"><img src="http://images.mycollegesabroad.com/smedia/uploads/images/article/india-and-africa-team-during-cii-exim-bank-conclave/images%20(26).jpg" style="float:left;"></a> 
<a onclick="decrease_text(1)" href="#"><img src="http://files.intf.in/guptaagency/wgc_media/photos/images%20(9).jpg" style="float:left;"></a>
</div>